# how to use plugin/other module for add html for other module in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, layout, frontend, plugin, html

- I want to **render html** (Front-side) using **plugin**/other module in **different** module.

---

1. There's already existing form in **Module X**.
2. I want add **one drop-down** in that from using **Module Y**.
3. How can i achieve this using **Plugins**/Module Y ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that Module X is having a block class that extends from `Magento\Framework\Element\Template`. In your own Module Y, you can define a plugin for this block class and for the `setTemplate()` method.

Your code would go something like this:

```
<?php

class TemplatePlugin {

public method afterSetTemplate(...) {

return 'Vendor_ModuleY::my_custom_template.phtml';
}
```

Then simply copy the template from Module X to your Module Y and do the changes there.
Also, add a `<sequence />` to your `module.xml` of Module Y to make sure that module is loaded after Module X.

Comment: Thanks for the answer +1, I try and update you back :)

Answer (score 1):

I followed these steps Using different module -to render HTML on specific location in Other module.

My New module

> Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/vendorModule_product_create.xml

`vendorModule_product_create.xml` is same **layout** file name - Which i want add new HTML in Other module.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

    <referenceBlock name="vendor.product.offers">
        <block class="RB\RFQuote\Block\Offers" name="rbvendor_offers_rfq" template="form/offers.phtml">
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</page>
```

1. **This is reference** - `<referenceBlock name="vendor.product.offers">`

   ---
2. **This is defined in Other module's Layout file** as  `<block
   name="vendor.product.offers">`
3. **I created a Block and HTML file** `<block
   class="Vendor\Module\Block\Offers" name="vendormodule_offers_rfq"
   template="form/offers.phtml"></block>`

> Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/form/offers.phtml

- Your HTML goes here.

> Vendor/Module/Block/Offers.php

```
class Offers extends Template
{

    /**
     * @param Template\Context $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {

        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
}
```

4. **And FINALLY call this function in your Other module** where you
   wanted to render HTML.

   ---

   **$block->getChildHtml('vendormodule_offers_rfq');**